# How to add and subtract value of sum after adding/removing a row from JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, addition, subtraction

I have the code for adding and removing a single row for my `JTable` but it causes problems like not providing accurate calculation of overall sum and subtraction after removing it from the `JTable`. The `JTable` serves as a "cart" for adding and removing items in the cart.

The `add to cart` button for adding a row to the cart:

```
if (e.getSource() == movebutton) {
        TableModel model1 = productTable.getModel();
        int index[] = productTable.getSelectedRows();
        Object[] row = new Object[4];
        DefaultTableModel model2 = (DefaultTableModel) cartTable.getModel();

        for (int i = 0; i < index.length; i++) {
            row[0] = model1.getValueAt(index[i], 0);
            row[1] = model1.getValueAt(index[i], 1);
            row[2] = model1.getValueAt(index[i], 2);
            model2.addRow(row);
            getSum();
        }
```

The code where it adds the overall items:

```
public void getSum() {  //column 02 is where the item's prices are listed
    for (int i = 0; i < cartTable.getRowCount(); i++) {
        total += Double.parseDouble(cartTable.getValueAt(i, 2).toString()); 
    }
    cartAmount.setText("Total: P " + Double.toString(total));
}
```

}

The `remove an item from the cart` button code:

```
 try {
            for (int i = 0; i < cartTable.getRowCount(); i++) {
                total = total - Double.parseDouble(cartTable.getValueAt(i, 2).toString());
            }
            cartAmount.setText("Total: P " + Double.toString(total));
            if (total <= 0.0) {
                total = 0.0;
            }
            {
                int getSelectedRowForDeletion = cartTable.getSelectedRow();
                model2.removeRow(getSelectedRowForDeletion);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Item removed from cart");
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
        }
    }
```

Here are some pics when adding and remove an item:
[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I also make the remove button to not work when no row is selected? Like ask the user to select a row before deletion? Also remove the possibility of having negative sum calculations. Thank you

Comment: Your data model for the JTables should not be the TableModel.  You should be keeping this information in plain old Java classes.  The TableModel would get its information from the data model.  The action listener of your buttons is where you do calculations.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Ok, I removed TableModel and used DefaultTableModel. Also, I removed the getSum(); and inserted the calculation in the the add to cart button. Still the same results :(

Answer (score 0):

I solved it:

The add to cart button:

```
 if (e.getSource() == movebutton) {
        try {
            int index[] = productTable.getSelectedRows();
            Object[] row = new Object[4];

            for (int i = 0; i < index.length; i++) {
                row[0] = model.getValueAt(index[i], 0);
                row[1] = model.getValueAt(index[i], 1);
                row[2] = model.getValueAt(index[i], 2);
                model2.addRow(row);
            }
            DefaultTableModel t = (DefaultTableModel) productTable.getModel();
            int selectedRow = productTable.getSelectedRow();
                {
                    total += Double.parseDouble(t.getValueAt(selectedRow, 2).toString());
                }
                cartAmount.setText("Total: P " + Double.toString(total));
            }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException a) {
        }
    }
```

The remove button:

```
if (e.getSource() == remove) {
        try {
            DefaultTableModel t = (DefaultTableModel) cartTable.getModel();
            int getSelectedRowForDeletion = cartTable.getSelectedRow();
            if (getSelectedRowForDeletion >= 0) {
                int selectedRow = cartTable.getSelectedRow();
                total -= Double.parseDouble(t.getValueAt(selectedRow, 2).toString());
                cartAmount.setText("Total: P " + Double.toString(total));
                model2.removeRow(getSelectedRowForDeletion);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Item removed from cart!");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Select an item to remove.");
            }
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException a) {
        }
    }
```

I removed the for loop when adding the values as it will just add the next item in the productTable. Same goes for the remove button.